# C - Getting correct pointer from a function and printing through another function

Tags: c, pointers

I have some trouble with pointing my `pointer` to the correct "box", to make it print a `number` using `linked list`s through a second `function`. I wont copy my whole code since it would be a bit of cheating, and my point is to learn. So I will write a simple example of what I want to do...

```
typedef struct{
     int number;
     struct node *next;
} mystruct;

void main()
{
    char numb[1000];

    scanf("%s",numb);
    mystruct *head=malloc(sizeof(mystruct));
    CreateList(numb, &head);
    PrintList(head);
}

CreateList(char x[1000],mystruct **head)
{
    int i;
    int digits=strlen(x)
    for (i=0;i<digits;i++)
    {
         // creating the linked list. meaning each digit of number going into a "box"
    }
}
```

Now if I want to access the "boxes" meaning for instance create another function which prints `numb`.

Example of display:

**12345** `//user input`

12345

Comment: I am not sure how to "return" the pointers address or even where to give it an address. its kind of confusing. Its probably because I'm still a beginner but still this should be something that should be understandable at this point. Not sure what my mistake is

Comment: "*So I will write a simple example of what I want to do...*" which you didn't.

Comment: @alk I realize that... basically this is what I mean. User gives a number. 12345 for example. By using a pointer each digit of the number becomes an element in a list. Then I want to print the number on the screen using the pointer to print each element of the list that has been created. I can't explain it any easier than that.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int number;
    struct node *next;
} mystruct;

void CreateList(char x[1000], mystruct **head);
void PrintList(mystruct *head);
void FreeList(mystruct *head);

int main(void){
    char numb[1000];

    scanf("%999s", numb);
    mystruct *head;

    CreateList(numb, &head);
    PrintList(head);
    FreeList(head);
    return 0;
}

void CreateList(char x[1000], mystruct **head){
    mystruct *currNode, *newNode;
    *head = NULL;
    int i;
    for (i=0;x[i];i++){//x[i] != '\0'
        if(NULL == (newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode)))){
            perror("error of malloc");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if(i==0){
            *head = currNode = newNode;
        }
        newNode->number = x[i];//x[i] - '0'
        newNode->next = NULL;
        currNode = currNode->next = newNode;
    }
}
void PrintList(mystruct *head){
    while(head){
        printf("%c", head->number);//%d
        head = head->next;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
void FreeList(mystruct *head){
    while(head){
        mystruct *temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}
```